# Change the color of one character using JQuery without changing HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I am trying to iterate through the DOM using JQuery and I want to change the color of every instance of the letter m. this is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var m = "<span style='color: red;'>m</span>"

$("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/m/g, m));
   });
});
```

The problem with this is that it also modifies the html elements like links in `<href>` and `<img>`

I tried using

```
if (!$(this).is("a")) { //replace }
```

but that didn't work. also using .text() instead of .html() didn't work for me

Comment: So as long as all your text is written between the tags (not as some weird attribute or in css) you could iterate through all your textNodes and just replace their content.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you want, you need to have a recursive fonction. In that function, you have to check if the element is a text node. Once you have a text node, you can then replace it's content. Else, you need to call the same function with the new element.

Here the said function :

```
letterScanner( $('body'), 'm' )

function letterScanner( $el, letter ){
  $el.contents().each( function(){
    if( this.nodeType == 3 ){
      $( this ).replaceWith( this.textContent.replace( new RegExp( '('+letter+'+)', 'g' ), "<span style='color: red;'>$1</span>" ) );
    }else{
        letterScanner( $( this ), letter )
    }
  } );
}
```

Of course, change the `body` selector for the closest parent for better performance.

https://jsfiddle.net/ghb4p1p8/